# Get a list of functions evaluated

Tags: debugging, functions

I am trying to track down a weird bug in my emacs configuration - the cursor, occasionally, jumps to a random location when I am scrolling using the arrow keys, in `cc-mode`. I don't see any accidental keystrokes registered in `view-lossage`. Is there a way to get a list of all functions called, instead of just the commands displayed by `view-lossage`?

Answer (score 2):

Listing *every* function that got called would be unreadable I'm sure (lots of functions calling functions calling functions). You might try `command-log-mode`, available via the package manager or from https://github.com/lewang/command-log-mode.

Comment: Thanks! The description says "keystrokes get logged into a designated buffer, along with the command bound to them.". Other than the time-stamping feature, isn't this pretty much `view-lossage`? While every function called would be very verbose, I am at a loss for debugging ideas and am looking for something that would act as an elisp tracer.

Comment: Yes, but with nicer presentation, since it's showing one command per line rather than just the sequence of keystrokes.